# Identity the event triggered element from a array of elements in Hammer

Tags: jquery, hammer.js

I have two html divs like this:

```
<div class="div-class" data-val="1">Div 1</div>
<div class="div-class" data-val="2">Div 2</div> 
<div class="div-class" data-val="2">Div 2</div>
```

Using jquery I can get the correct value of data-val when I click each div.

```
var el = $('.div-class');
el.on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).data('val'));  //pop up value '1', '2' or '3' based on click
});
```

But when I try to do this with Hammer on event doubletap like below, it shows all three values without correctly identifying my click.

```
var el = $('.div-class');
Hammer(el).on('doubletap', function(){
    alert($(this).data('val')); //all three values are shown
});
```

How can I get only the correct value based on my click event?
(Do not worry about the different of events.)

Answer (score 2):

The Hammer handler function is passed the `event` as a parameter, as such you can use `event.target`:

```
var el = $('.div-class');
Hammer(el).on('doubletap', function(event){
    alert($(event.target).data('val'));
});
```

For more information on the properties you can get from the `event` see the 'Event Data' section of the [Hammer docs](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: But still all three values are shown. I think function is activated for all three element in 'el' array.

Comment: Are the values shown in 3 separate alerts, or one single one?

Comment: In that case, yes the event is being raised for every `.div-class` element individually. I can't really help any more than that with the code you've provided as it should be working.